The Famous Five
What does this picture represent and why?


I think it represents

 The Simpson Family

In order

 Picture 1 looks like Homer's head viewed from above.
 Picture 2 looks like the outline of Marge's hair.
 Picture 3 looks like Bart's hair from above.
 Picture 4 looks like the outline of Lisa's hair.
 Picture 5 looks like the outline of Maggie's hair with the red dot representing the pacifier.


Nice work! Out of curiosity how long did it take for you to get it?

@PDT Maybe about 10-15 minutes, I think I immediately put it in my head the resemblance of the second image  and then only after some time following this thread. Nice puzzle idea
